# Identifying which tab in Google Chrome is responsible for error messages

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

I keep lots of tabs open in Google Chrome, and sometimes get mysterious indications of problems.

This error message is currently coming up every minutes or two in the console window from which I launched Chrome:

> [18872:18892:183710218970:ERROR:sync_resource_handler.cc(50)] Cross origin redirect denied

The first number there is the process id for the main chrome "browser" process.  I haven't figured out what the others are, or exactly what the error means, but it sounds like some page might have a CSRF vulnerability.  I'm running Chrome version 13.0.782.107 beta, on Ubuntu Linux.

How/what can I use to track the tab that is causing problems?

Comment: Why did you launch chrome from a console window?

Comment: @wizlog So I could see the errors.  Actually, I run it like this to get time-stamped errors, where "teetime" is a simple unbuffered perl script to prepend a timestamp: google-chrome 2>&1| teetime >> /tmp/chrome-errs

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the log level 
Here's a decent page with descriptions of [chrome cli switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
Enabling logging, changing the log level and printing the page text  are the first things I'd try.

```
     --enable-logging  --log-level 0 --print
```

Comment: It looks like an equals sign needs to be used for arguments: --log-level=0

Comment: I tried this and it didn't provide anything that seems relevant to tracking down the errors I'm seeing.  But +1 for that amazingly long list of command-line options!